#  concatenate an html tag inside an asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need to concatenate an HTML tag like `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` to the `Text` property of an ASP.Net TextBox.

I tried this:

```
txtMessage.Text + "<br/>" + strgetlist;
```

But it is displaying the following:

> TaskName`<br/>`Project1,project2..

How cam I add a break/space between these two strings?

Comment: Have you tried using '\n' instead? Hopefully asp.net will handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am assuming that the output is to be shown in a TextBox.  First make the TextBox `TEXTMODE` as multiline.  Then on the TextBox where you have to show the output (say txtOutput), you write:

```
txtOutput = TextBox1.Text + "\n" + strgetlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `txtMessage.Text + "<br/>" + strgetlist`

Comment: ya i have used this oly ,bt im getting <br/> printed out

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment.NewLine as long as you have set TextMode="MultiLine" for the TextBox. Just a plain space (i.e. " ") should work to get a space in the 'list'.

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -1):

you could try using string.Format

`string.Format("{0}<br />{1}", txtMessage.Text, strgetlist);`